# Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points?

Tags: gps

I need to calculate distance between two GPS points.  I found this function in earlier post:

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1);

  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);

  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km

  return d;
}
```

I  tried it, and it does not make sense.  Let's say I did not move, thus `lat1` and `lat2` are the same. So, `dLat` and `dLon` would both be 0.  Thus, term `a` would be 0.  Term `c = 2 * Math.atan2(0,1) = 3.141593` (I used Excel to get this number), and the distance `d = 20015.08 km`.

I am calculating distance of a vehicle moving every second given two GPS points. I am expecting small number.  What is wrong here?

Comment: Hey, spherical Earth!  What could go wrong...?

Comment: Passing the same Longitued and Latitude yields 0. What are you providing for `lon1`, `lon2`?

Comment: Lat is 33.03475, and Long is -117.112.  So, lat in rad is 0.57656519 and long in rad is -2.043991041. dLat and dLon are both 0.  So var a term is 0 because sin(0) = 0.  var c = 2 * atan2(0,1) = 1.570796,  var d = 6371 * 1.570796 = 10007.54 km.  What am I missing here?

Comment: It does not matter what the input lat and long are if they are the same, var a is reduced to 0.  Thus the equation reduces to 2 * atan2(0,1) which is none 0.  Multiply the result by 6371, then the result is big.  I must be missing something.  What is it?

Comment: In addition, var c is always very close to the value of pi.  This is because the var a is either very small number or 0, so atan2 is always close to atan2(0,1) which is half of pi.  So, var c is always close to pi.  So, distance d would be close to 6371 * pi = 2015 km. How did this function ever work?

Comment: Typo....I meant 20015 km.

Comment: Please read my answer, it answers exatly your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used this code - it worked fine.

```
    public static double distance(MyLocation p1, MyLocation p2) {
    double theta = p1.mLongitude - p2.mLongitude;
    String unit = "K";
    double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(p1.mLatitude)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(p2.mLatitude))
            + Math.cos(deg2rad(p1.mLatitude)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(p2.mLatitude)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = rad2deg(dist);
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    if (unit == "K") {
        dist = dist * 1.609344;



    } else if (unit == "N") {
        dist = dist * 0.8684;
    }

    return (dist);
}
```

it calculates distances in kilometers.

Comment: Hi Dennis,  If the vehicle comes to a stop, thus p1.mLatitude and p2.mLatitude are the same.  So, dist would be square of sin of lat + square of cos of lat.  The theta is 0, so cos of that is 1.  The dist would be none zero, when it should be zero.  I get similar result with the previous algorithm.  When vehicle comes to a stop and lat and long is the same, i.e. not moving, the distance is huge...thousand of km.  I can make special case for when theta is 0, but why?  What am I missing?

Comment: There are hundreds of posts here showing distance formulas. This is one is not made for comupters. It is one made for navigators using a paper and pencil and an hand caluclator. The unit of length is meters. Everything else is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you are using is called Haversine Formula.
It works very well, and is especially suited to work short distances, too.
I checked your code to my implementation, I see one error your implementtaion

The haversine formula you are using should use the earth radius in meters, why do you use kilomters for R?

Your question:

> "Term c = 2 * Math.atan2(0,1) = 3.141593 (I used Excel to get this number)"

This is the error in your asumption. The term c = 0. Glad, that you mentioned Excell. Excell uses reversed order for arguments of atan2(), in excell you must write atan2(1,0).

Further:
If correction of R to unit meters does not help make sure
that all vars are of type double.
When I see you code, I have fear that somewhere an double gets silently converted to an int.

If that all does not help:
Please show an example input of lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2 and the intermediate values for a and c. and make sure your deg2rad() works. (After you corrected R to meters)

Answer (score 0):

There is a general purpose function available on https://github.com/grekowski/AzimuthJS

You can calculate distance in any units and you can decide if you want a great-circle or rhumb-line method It's in JavaScript but it's quite easy to convert to Java if needed.

You can install it to your front end from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/grekowski/AzimuthJS@latest/dist/azimuth.min.js